# Link to bookmark of another google doc?

Tags: google-docs

I'm trying to link to a bookmark contained in another google doc.

So far, I use `cmd + k` to add a link -> Find more -> Drive

But when I click on the actual document containing the bookmark I want to link to, it opens it, rather than showing me the bookmarks it contains so I can select one to link to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the google doc you want to link to
2. Create a bookmark somewhere inside it (Insert -> Bookmark)
3. Click on the bookmark you want to link to, click 'Link' (notice the url in the browser address bar has changed - that new url is the url that includes the bookmark)
4. Copy the entire url and link to it!

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

1. Open the google doc you want to link to
2. Create a bookmark somewhere inside it (Insert -> Bookmark)
3. Click the bookmark icon.
4. On the popup, click the "copy" icon.
5. In your "destination" document, place your cursor where you want it
6. Click Insert --> Link
7. In the second field (not the one labeled "Text"), paste the URL you copied, and click "Apply"